# React.js: How to prevent wasted renders when inserting a new form field on the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I have a form with a couple of conditionally rendered fields. The form is made up of MUI components, react-hook-form and yup for its validation.

Additionally, I have added a `console.log()` within the `AutocompleteCoffee`, `RadioBtnGroup`,  `TxtField` components that will execute every time the components are rendered.

**Scenario**

When the page loads you can see a log from each component. Nothing new here.

When you select "Yes" from,  Do you like coffee? a new field will be rendered. This action triggers a rerender of all the components on the page.

I am using the `watch` method from react-hook-form to keep track of the question mentioned above.

```
const coffee = watch("coffee", "No");
...
{coffee === "Yes" ? (
          <AutocompleteCoffee
            required
            fullWidth
            name="coffeType"
            label="Which coffee type"
            control={control}
            options={coffeList}
            error={!!errors.coffeType}
            helperText={errors?.coffeType?.message}
          />
        ) : null}
...
```

You can see the working [CodeSandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-rerenders-2t102s?file=/src/components/MainForm.js).

**Question**

I was wondering how to prevent all the wasted renders. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: useCallback or React.memo

Comment: Where? @RoyChristo, the `AutocompleteCoffee`, the `coffee` variable, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I've got this performance issue once. As [per docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch), you should switch to callback way of calling `watch` or to useWatch

```
This API will trigger re-render at the root of your app or form, 
consider using a callback or the useWatch API
if you are experiencing performance issues.
```

code would look like:

instead of your coffee check, do `<MaybeCoffee control={control} errors={errors} />` and remove watch("coffee", "No") as well.

Then add a component MaybeCoffee:

```
const MaybeCoffee = ({ control, errors }) => {
  const coffee = useWatch({ control, name: "coffee" }) || "No";
  return coffee === "Yes" ? (
    <AutocompleteCoffee
      required
      fullWidth
      name="coffeType"
      label="Which coffes type"
      control={control}
      options={coffeList}
      error={!!errors.coffeType}
      helperText={errors?.coffeType?.message}
    />
  ) : null;
}
```

an example https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-rerenders-forked-19invg?file=/src/components/MainForm.js

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, unless I misunderstood something,  all fields are still rerendering.  Here you code implemented https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-rerenders-forked-euts4v?file=/src/components/MaybeCoffee.js

Comment: useWatch() should be called in a child component, like in my link, otherwise, the fields will be rendered. Please follow the code in my link and the answer.

Comment: I am not sure why, but the code from your link is not working. That is why I created the second link. Thank you for your help and patience. @IgorLoskutov